# Grails Example applications not working for Angular, Vue and React

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, grails

I am in the learning process of Grails, and I have gotten the default example application HelloWorld work.

Running, building on Windows with WSL2 in OpenSUSE Leap 15.4.
Grails version 5.2.5

I then proceeded to try different profiles when creating the grails application, with Angular, React and Vue.

These did not go so well. Either something is missing from my configuration, JDK, Gradle, etc., and/or perhaps the generated projects need to be updated to use newer JDK and Gradle.

Perhaps I should report these problems on the Grails Profile GitHub.
https://github.com/grails-profiles/angular/issues

https://github.com/grails-profiles/react/issues

https://github.com/grails-profiles/vue/issues

## **Web**

`grails create-app grails-test-web --profile=web`

Building and running the application works with both JDK-11/Gradle-7.2 and JDK-17/Gradle-7.6

## **Angular**

`grails create-app grails-test-angular --profile=angular`

The project was created with Gradle-5.1.1, and I used JDK-11 to build it.
It will not build.

`./gradlew bootRun --parallel`

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/djviking/workspace/grails-test-angular/server/build.gradle' line: 19

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':server'.
> Failed to apply plugin [class 'org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin.SpringBootPlugin']
   > Spring Boot plugin requires Gradle 6.8.x, 6.9.x, or 7.x. The current version is Gradle 5.1.1
```

Then I upgraded to Gradle 6.8.1, but that did not work either

```
> Configure project :server
Cannot resolve reloading agent JAR: Failed to resolve imported Maven boms: Cannot resolve external dependency org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.7.5 because no repositories are defined.
Required by:
    project :server

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/djviking/workspace/grails-test-angular/server/build.gradle' line: 19

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':server'.
> Receiver class grails.util.Environment does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract java.lang.Object getProperty(java.lang.String)' of interface groovy.lang.GroovyObject.
```

## **React**

`grails create-app grails-test-react --profile=react`

The project was created with Gradle-6.9, and I used JDK-11 to build it.
It will not build/start
`./gradlew server:bootRun`
`./gradlew client:start`

```
Cannot resolve reloading agent JAR: Failed to resolve imported Maven boms: Cannot resolve external dependency org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.7.5 because no repositories are defined.
Required by:
    project :server

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/svmoe/workspace/grails-test-react/server/build.gradle' line: 20

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':server'.
> Receiver class grails.util.Environment does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract java.lang.Object getProperty(java.lang.String)' of interface groovy.lang.GroovyObject.
```

## **Vue**

`grails create-app grails-test-vue --profile=vue`

The project was created with Gradle-6.9, and I used JDK-11 to build it.
It will not build the project.
`./gradlew server:bootRun`
`./gradlew client:serve`

```
> Configure project :server
Cannot resolve reloading agent JAR: Failed to resolve imported Maven boms: Cannot resolve external dependency org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:2.7.5 because no repositories are defined.
Required by:
    project :server

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/home/svmoe/workspace/grails-test-vue/server/build.gradle' line: 20

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':server'.
> Receiver class grails.util.Environment does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract java.lang.Object getProperty(java.lang.String)' of interface groovy.lang.GroovyObject.
```

Works with JDK 17, when I changed Gradle Wrapper to Gradle 7.6
`./gradlew server:bootRun`
I can access the URL, and I get a JSON structure.

```
  Grails application running at http://localhost:8080 in environment: development
```

`./gradlew client:serve`
I can not access the URL from this. Neither on localhost.

```
  App running at:
  - Local:   http://HOSTNAME:3000/
  - Network: http://HOSTNAME:3000/
```

Comment: I am trying to reproduce and cannot, but some of it isn't clear to me.  What version of Grails are you using?

Comment: Grails version 5.2.5